# Which resource equivalent to "GL_POLYGON" in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I need to draw a polygon in 3D space. 
Unable to find a resource that makes the 3D drawing in the Three.js.

For example to draw the following coordinates:

```
    (  x,    y,    z )
P1: (-200, -200, -200) 
P2: ( 200,  200,  200) 
P3: ( 150, -150,  150) 
P4: (-200, -200, -200)
```

The coordinate value "z" is not assigned, always getting zero.

```
var points = [];
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-200, -200, -200));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(200, 200, 200));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(150, -150, 150));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-200, -200, -200));           

var squareShape = new THREE.Shape( points );
var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( squareShape );      
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x357fff } );

var poligon = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add(poligon);
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Your question doesn't match the title, are you asking how to draw?
 You use glBegin(GL_POLYGON) and glEnd() for that.
 I only know how to use OpenGL in C++, so I won't be writing any actual code. Just to mention, even if you use GL_POLYGON, it will still be drawn as two triangles( there is a built-in algorithm that transforms it into calls with GL_TRIANGLES).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete tutorial of how to draw a simple primitive: [Three.js OpenGL tutorial lesson 2](http://www.johannes-raida.de/tutorials/three.js/tutorial02/tutorial02.htm)

You need to create a scene and add this mesh to the scene (`Scene.add(poligon );`). Then call `renderer.render(scene, camera);` and it will render to the screen.

Comment: I did it. But drawing the polygon is not  correct. Axis"z"is not being considered in the drawing, is always zero.

Comment: Then I guess that you render it using Orthogonal matrix, while you need to use Perspective one. In Orthogonal mode X and Y usually directly correspond to pixels on the screen and z is used only to make the impression of ,,layers''.

Comment: Actually you have not followed the example that @Vladivarius suggested. You would have noticed that THREE.Vector3 are added to THREE.Geometry and not to THREE.Shape which only takes THREE.Vector2

Comment: I used "THREE.Face4" and solve the problem. 
Must draw some triangles. 

Thanks @Vladivarius!